# jQuery/ajax call not hitting controller due large string data parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my view file, I'm making an ajax call as follows:

```
  debugger
        var url = '/Home/DetailUsageUser';
        var data2 = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 0).split(' ');
        var data1 = {  dateTime: data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 0), ServerID: ServerID, LicenseId: LicenseId, Company: company }
        $.get(url, data1)
            .done(function (response, status, jqxhr) {

                if (status === "success") {
                    $('#modal .modal-body').html(response);
                    $('#modal').modal('show');
                    $("#exportPopUpUserToExcel").show();
                }
                else {
                    /* your "email doesn't exist" action */
                }

            })
            .fail(function (jqxhr, status, errorThrown) {
                 var err = eval("(" + jqxhr.responseText + ")");
                 toastr.error(err.message);
            });
    };

    return false;
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
  public ActionResult DetailUsageUser(String dateTime, String serverID, String LicenseId, String Company)
    {
        TempData["Company"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Company) ? "" : Company;
        TempData["serverID"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverID) ? "" : serverID;
        TempData["dateTime"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTime) ? "" : dateTime;
        TempData["LicenseID"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(LicenseId) ? "" : LicenseId;

        var result = db1.SC_DetailUserInfo_BKP_15May2018(dateTime, serverID, LicenseId, Company);

        return PartialView("_DetailUsageUser", result);
    }
```

When the "company" value is smaller in length/size ajax call hits the controller action but when it is larger, it throws an error and it doesn't hit the controller method.
I have tried to rectify errors in many ways but not able to get it. With browser debugger, I am now getting following error.

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmisg.png)

Note: "company" variable contains the comma separated values from the multi-select drop-down.
Kindly put some light on it.

Comment: Make a POST instead of a GET (you issue is that you are exceeding the query string limit)

Comment: Yes. Issue resolved. Thanks :-)

Comment: Using both `$.post` and `[HttpPost]` should solve your issue now.